# NetworkPolicy: Allow all ports except specific one

Tags: kubernetes, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Here is the sample NetworkPolicy which allows connection to pods that have a label `hello` and allow port connection on 53 TCP and UDP and block all ports.

How I can make this to allow all ports and block 53 TCP and UDP (egress).

```yaml
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: foo-allow-to-hello
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: hello
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Kubernetes native NetworkPolicies don't have a 'deny' feature, so this will be very painful if you were to list every port that you want to allow except port `53`. Currently, there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67526) to allow port ranges in K8s network policies which would allow much more simplification.

With that said, there are other alternatives. If you are using an overlay like [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/resources/networkpolicy), you have access to a richer `NetworkPolicy` with actions. For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-dns
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  selector: app == 'hello'
  types:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  egress:
  - action: Deny
    metadata:
      annotations:
        from: helloworld
        to: dns
    protocol: TCP
    source:
      selector: app == 'hello'
    destination:
      ports:
      - 53
  - action: Deny
    metadata:
      annotations:
        from: helloworld
        to: dns
    protocol: UDP
    source:
      selector: app == 'hello'
    destination:
      ports:
      - 53
  ingress:
  - action: Allow
```

You can also find some other workarounds like applying an ingress policy to your coredns pods that allow certain pods/namespaces.

Comment: The feature request mentioned above is available. Recent K8s versions allow targeting a range of ports. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#targeting-a-range-of-ports